# Using JQuery MaskInput Plugin with a SSN Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the JQuery MaskInput plugin on a SSN field but I dont see anyway to make it display `"***-**-****"` after the user leaves the fields.

Did anyone get this working>

Comment: The plugin is not meant to mask it after the text has been entered. It only forces you to enter in the desired format.

Comment: do you know anyway to do it Josh?

Comment: give us some code. we let the crystal ball at home today

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but it may get you headed in the right direction. The masked input plugin has a completed function that can be called when the user has finished entering their value. You can use it to grab the value and store it in a hidden field to retain it and replace the current text with whatever you desire.

```
var $txt_SNN = $("#txt_SSN");

$txt_SNN.mask("999-99-9999", { 
    completed: function() {
         $('#hdf_SNN').val($txt_SNN.val());
         $txt_SNN.val("999-99-9999");
    }
});
```

Comment: is this the ONLY way?? I would think I can mask it

Comment: It is the simplest way that I know of. I will look into it if I have time, but otherwise you will most likely have to do other jquery manipulation of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt_SNN.mask("999-99-9999").blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'password');
});`
```

This should do it. Although I didn't test it.